# In response header Content-encoding: gzip is present, but in request header Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

In request header Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, is missing, but in response header Content-encoding: gzip is present. does it cause compression failed. if yes, how to avoid it??

Request URL:  http://something.com/something.js

Request Method:  GET

Status Code:  200 OK  200 OK

Request Headers

```
Accept:  */*
Referer:  somthing.comsomthing.aspx
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:  2D3ED9B5-95BD-4984-9EEE-405C2889F11E
```

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  884
Content-Type:  application/x-javascript
Date:  Tue, 28 Oct 2014 11:09:13 GMT
ETag:  "0ac99ce3e9fcf1:0"
Last-Modified:  Mon, 14 Jul 2014 08:37:12 GMT
Server:  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary:  Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:  ASP.NET
```

Comment: Who is making the request, a random browser or you, from code? Why is the request header missing? Is the entire accept-encoding header missing, or just the "gzip, deflate" part? Whether the client can decode the response, depends on the client. You can avoid this by providing the proper headers, granted the server respects them. In conclusion: your question is way too vague. Please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't get that who is making request, request header is present but in request header accept-encoding:gzip part is missing.

Comment: @CodeCaster elaborated in question, please have look and give solution if there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-41):

> A request without an Accept-Encoding header field implies that the
> user agent has no preferences regarding content-codings.  Although
> this allows the server to use any content-coding in a response, it
> does not imply that the user agent will be able to correctly process
> all encodings.

In short: if you specify no `Accept-Encoding`, it's legal (though ill-advised) for the server to send you compressed content. There doesn't appear to be a solid, reliable way to tell a web server that it should definitely not compress. You can try `Accept-Encoding: *;q=0` or `Accept-Encoding: identity`, but support for this is not universal across web servers, and proxies can mess things up as well.

In the end you are probably better off with simply handling compressed content if it comes back as such -- there is no good reason for a client to not support compression and libraries for this are freely available.